# Visual Studio Iot Application for Raspberry Pi

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

I have installed the Windows 10 IoT on my Raspberry Pi 2. How can I create a form application that will run on the Pi ?
I have already installed Windows Iot Core in my Visual Studio, but now it only says Background Application (IoT), but I want to create some graphics with text displayed...

Comment: I think you can run an universal app on windows 10 core

Comment: But how do I then add a form so that i can edit the text and so on... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the IoT Core templates for Visual Studio 2015 from here:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55b357e1-a533-43ad-82a5-a88ac4b01dec

On Windows 10 IoT core, you can run Windows 10 Universal applications (UWP) with a visual interface. In Visual Studio, start a new "Universal Windows" project with your chosen programming language. You can then code a GUI with for example XAML just like a desktop or mobile Windows 10 application. For example for C# use *Visual C# -> Universal -> Blank App (Universal Windows)*.

You need the Windows SDK but that is included in the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

To access the unique features of the device (like GPIO) you need to add a reference to "Windows IoT Extension SDK".

**Examples on how to do it:**

- See this repository for samples of many kinds of different apps (you can just download a ZIP of all those and play with them): https://github.com/ms-iot/samples
- Tutorials for the samples: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/startcoding